# Plot Axis in Python with Log Scale for Negative Exponents of 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot my y-axis using a logarithmic scale. `yscale("log")` or `yscale("symlog")` only scales the axis for *positive* powers of 10, i.e. `10^1, 10^2, 10^3`, etc. My data are mainly less than one. Therefore I need to plot a y axis scaled to `10^-1, 10^-2, 10^-3`, all the way to `10^-9` or `10^-10`. How could I go about doing this? Much thanks.

Comment: I tried it and had no problems.

Comment: are you using `plt.semilogy` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I need a *scatter* plot in particular. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

We use `.set_yscale('log')` on the axes simply. Here a simple example:

```
# Create sample data
x = np.arange(0, 20)
y = np.linspace(1e-9, 1e-1, 20)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o--')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
```

[image: example_log_y]