# Plotting xscale with negative powers of 10 in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question. I'm having trouble plotting an array of negative powers of 10 in matplotlib

I have read through all of the log xscale options in the matplotlib documentation but to no avail. I have also read the following questions and some others which seemed similar but they did not end up helping me out:

[Matplotlib: disable powers of ten in log plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637689/matplotlib-disable-powers-of-ten-in-log-plot)

[Plot Axis in Python with Log Scale for Negative Exponents of 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812880/plot-axis-in-python-with-log-scale-for-negative-exponents-of-10)

[Logscale plots with zero values in matplotlib *with negative exponents*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268202/logscale-plots-with-zero-values-in-matplotlib-with-negative-exponents)

[Logscale plots with zero values in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904755/logscale-plots-with-zero-values-in-matplotlib)

This is more or less in simple form what my code looks like.

x = np array with 100 values of 0.99999, 0.9999, 0.999, 0.99

y = np array with corresponding evaluation outputs to be plotted.

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xticks([0.99999,0.9999,0.999,0.99])
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
```

What I'm trying to attain is a plot with just the values 0.99999, 0.9999, 0.999, 0.99 evenly spaced on the x axis plotted against their corresponding y values.

Once again I would like to thank you so much for taking the time to read this question, and I sincerely hope you can help me out!

Comment: Could you post a minimal and complete example, including some copy-pastable example data?

Comment: `0.99999,0.9999,0.999,0.99` is not a logarithmic progression, so it is no surprise it is not evenly-spaced with a log scale. Have you considered plotting `1-x` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily "fake" this kind of plot, by plotting y against `[0,1,2,3,...]` and then replacing the xtickslabel with `[0.9999,0.999,0.99,...]`

```
x = [0.99999,0.9999,0.999,0.99]
y = [1,2,3,4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(len(x)),y, 'o-')
ax.set_xticks(range(len(x)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer lead me on the path to create the plot that I wanted. Very much appreciated!!